# Handling Transaction management in a large application

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, concurrency, transactions

I have a situation like in a Java application like , "if an there is an entry in a table and simultaneously there is a delete request also how will we handle such a scenario".

Could anybody suggest me on how to deal with issues like these which could work on small as well as large applications?

Comment: Do the delete request?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if there is an insert and delete request received simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, but then there could be this other user who is making an entry to the database table, what do we tell him? How do we handle these kind of issues?

Comment: @skip I have never head of a database that can't apply two concurrent writes

Comment: @Manish Yes, I meant many people working with the same database table row.

Comment: You should read more about database transactions, and then how they are implemented in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is how the UI/UX should be handled when such scenario occurs. Besides the concurrency issue described in question, there can be other scenarios like user 1 opens edit person page, in the mean time, user2 deletes that record from another login. What should happen when user1 tries to save the record?

You should probably return an error message to the user stating the details of the error(record deleted, updated by someone else etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very wide and such is the aswer.

I will narrow the problem a bit, by assuming you are using spring(boot). If so then It is very easy to answer.
Use the @Transactional annotation above the methods that contain the logic to either save or delete. And include required libraries ofc.

With the methods annontated in such a way, the spring(boot) application will guarantee that both operations will occur in the order that is required to maintain a consistent database.

If an error occurs, you can handle this in higher levels of your application or just show an error to the user.